# On a Functor instance declaration

Tags: haskell

This loads without error:

```
data Const c a = Const c

instance Functor (Const c) where
    fmap _ (Const v) = Const v
```

...but this

```
data Const' c a = Const' c

instance Functor (Const' c) where
    fmap _ cv = cv
```

...fails with:

```
    Couldn't match type `a' with `b'
      `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for fmap :: (a -> b) -> Const' c a -> Const' c b
          at test.hs:4:5
      `b' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for fmap :: (a -> b) -> Const' c a -> Const' c b
          at test.hs:4:5
    Expected type: Const' c b
      Actual type: Const' c a
    In the expression: cv
    In an equation for `fmap': fmap _ cv = cv
    In the instance declaration for `Functor (Const' c)'
```

I don't understand the error.  Why can't the compiler infer that the type of `cv` is `Const' c`?  What else could it be, given the rest of the declaration, and the definition of `fmap`?

Comment: Fortunately, taking off the `Const` constructor and putting it back on are free, since `Const` is a newtype. The situation is much sadder for `Either`, where memory may need to be allocated to change the type even if the representation stays the same.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to be fully explicit, you can write

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables, InstanceSigs #-}

data Const c a = Const c

instance Functor (Const c) where
    fmap :: forall a b. (a -> b) -> Const c a -> Const c b
    fmap _ (Const v :: Const c a) = Const v :: Const c b
```

Which is a bit of a mouthful. :-)

`forall a b.` brings `a` and `b` into scope so they can be referred to in the definition.  This is enabled by `ScopedTypeVariables`.  `InstanceSigs` allows us to write the signature of `fmap` in the first place (normally it *must* be inferred from the class, so we have nowhere to get the type variable names from).

Comment: Are you sure `c` should be quantified there? It seems to me that `c` should be the one implicitly bound by the instance head.

Comment: You are right. I quantified c at the last minute but it is incorrect. Fixed

Comment: (Deleted my earlier comment, since it's now obsolete.  Will delete this one as well, in a few minutes.)

Answer (score 7):

`cv` is of type `Const' c a`, so it can't also be of type `Const' c b` (unless `a ~ b`). `Const v` and `Const v`, however, can be of different types.

Another way of looking at it is that `fmap _ cv = cv` is equivalent to `fmap _ = id`, which would be of type `Const' c a -> Const' c a`, but `fmap _` must be of type `Const' c a -> Const' c b`.

Comment: Yet another way of looking at it is that haskell syntax makes type parameters implicit, and infers them from context.  The full form of the definition is `fmap _ (Const {c a} v) = Const {c b} v` (where `{}` denotes type application), which makes it clear that the two sides of the equation are different.

Comment: @luqui:  Is there a way to write the full form of the definition that the compiler will accept?  I've tried several variants of what you showed, but the compiler rejects all of them.

Comment: @kjo What luqui showed is not real syntax. You can't use it in Haskell programs.

Comment: @kjo, I added an answer with the most explicit form I know

Comment: @ReinHenrichs: I got that, but I thought that he meant that the form `fmap _ (Const v) = Const v` was a shorthand (for a "full form") allowed by the compiler.  If this interpretation is correct, I figure that there must indeed be a "full form", one that does not rely on any compiler-allowed shortcuts, and if so, I'd like to know what this full form is.

Comment: No, there's no other "full form" (aside from explicit type annotations), and I'm not sure why you think any "compiler-allowed shortcuts" are being used.

Comment: @kjo: Type application - instantiating a polymorphic definition at a monomorphic type - is always implicit in Haskell. If I understand correctly, internally, GHC elaborates Haskell code into a Core language based on (an extension of) System Fω, where type application is explicit.